# http get request returning multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I am new to this API thing, and I am kind of stuck on something. I have to create a get request that gets all devs by their teamId. I tried something but it's not working because there are more matching endpoints. So I guess my question is, how can I return all those. Here are the models

```
public class Dev
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public override string? ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
    
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public override string? ToString()
    {
    return $"{Id}, {Name}, {Size}";
    }
}
```

I tried

```
[HttpGet("{teamId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Dev>> GetDevByTeamId(int teamId)
{
    var dev=await _context.Devs.FindAsync(teamId);

    if (dev == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return dev;

}
```

So, as I said, I want to get all the devs from teamId. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is it returning currently ?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.